# Location of declaraing state in React

Tags: reactjs

I used to declare state in App.jsx which is the root component. But I wonder if it's okay to declare it in sub-components too.

For example, let's say there are 5 components and the structure is like below.

App > Home > Section1, Section2 > Button

And I wanna display the data in `Button` of each `Section`

Now is it okay to declare state in `Home` component instead of `App`? Which is recommended?

- Edit) I know it works good in both cases but I wanna know what's common.

Comment: Sure. Declare state at the lowest level possible in the hierarchy that still gets the job done. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/388055

Comment: Ideally, states should be declared and used within components itself, unless it is required to passed to different components (which should be done via passing props or `useContext`. If you are only going to use it in `Section` and nowhere else, declare it in `Section`.

Comment: It's completely fine and recommended. I usually declare state in component which that state refer to.

Comment: @cSharp Here there are 2 `Section` components, Section1 and Section2. So I asked the question regarding `Home` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a state variable anywhere in the component tree. In fact, deciding where the state should live is the corner stone of React Development, so congrats you're on the right path!

*Generally speaking*, you'd place the state at *the closest common ancestor to all the child component that consumes it through props*. Because :

- You want all your components that share the same logical information to share the same state variable. That's what react is about, a single source of truth.
- You want your state to live as close as possible to your components to avoid [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling)

Of course this is **very** generic advice, and a ton of factors can influence this decision. A good starting point would be to read [This article from React's doc on lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). It goes through the process of deciding where the state should live step by step on a concrete use case.